# why is my error handling not working in express js?

Tags: node.js, json, express, asynchronous, error-handling

i just need someone to tell me what is wrong with my code. This is it.

```
const getSingletask = async (req, res)=>

{

    try{
        const task = await Task.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        if(!task){
            return res.json({msg:`No such task with and id of ${req.params.id}`})
        }
        res.json({task})

    }catch(error){
        res.json({msg:error})
    }
}
```

Basically what the code is doing is that whenever the function excutes, it finds one particular item using its ID. The IF statement is the first error handler. It is meant to return that message if the ID cannot be found but it keeps bringing up an error anytime i test it out. I think my code is correct so can someone tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: Can you add details of the error to your post?

Comment: this is the error message  =  "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"619e6c49d\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"tasks\""

Comment: "619e6c49d" is the id i am using to check for my error handler as i mentioned before

Comment: The error message may be coming from the `catch`.  You can test this by temporarily altering it to something like

    `res.json({msg:\`in the catch block ${error}\`})`
Then if the error comes back that includes the string, you know the `try/catch` is working.  It would be good to confirm this part.

Comment: From the error message it appears that it's expecting an Object but `req.params.id` is a string.

Comment: your right , i just checked. it is from the catch. I have no idea why the catch error handler is happening before the if statement. Plus i still have no idea why it is finding any error in the first place because my i think the code is correct. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The catch error occurred because it tried the code in the `try` block but the database threw an error and so that was caught by the `catch` block and outputted.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using mongoose. Mongoose saves db objects by way of a wrapper called ObjectId, that accepts exactly [24 hex characters](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids). Because the ID you are inputting into it is not 24 hex characters, mongoose fails to cast it (meaning to use the wrapper), and so, throws an error.

Comment: oh wow thanks i just tested it with 24 hex characters and it finally worked. gracias